# Programming Rookie - Limiting From 2 Tables

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to determine "First Time Givers", people who gave in FY2015 but never given before. I also need to ignore users who gave for a certain reason (appealCode).

Below is example of some of the fields my tables have and what information needs limited.

```
 **FundLedger**         
 Account ID EntryAmount GiftReceivedDt  AppealCode
 1000              $500     7/1/2014    1
 1000              $500     2/2/2002    2
 2000               $25     8/1/2014    1
 2000               $25     9/1/2014    1
 3000              $100     10/1/2014   1
 4000            $1,000     11/1/2014   2

 **ConstituentTotals**          
 ConstituentID  FirstTransactionDate    LastTransactionDate CashAmount
          1000              2/2/2002               1/1/2014     $1,000 
          2000              3/1/2014               4/1/2014        $50 
          3000              5/1/2014               5/1/2014       $100 
          4000             11/1/2014              11/1/2014     $1,000
```

What I need is to find the number of constituents who gave between 6/1/2014 and today, who have never given before, and the gift was not given to AppealCode 2.

So the number I need from the sample information is '2'.

```
 **Information Needed**             
 ConstituentID  CashAmount  FirstTransactionDate    LastTransactionDate   AppealCode
          2000         $50              3/1/2014            4/1/2014            1
          3000        $100              5/1/2014            5/1/2014            1
```

As of now I can either get the number of people who gave if I ignore the AppealCode, or I can get the AppealCode limited but I get ALL transactions of the giver.

Currently at this stage, it pulls the count 77,000 times, one for each entry in the Ledger.

```
'SELECT
Number_Of_New_Donors = ( SELECT  COUNT(a.ConstituentID) 
                From dbo.FundConstituentTotals a
                RIGHT JOIN dbo.FundLedger b
                ON a.ConstituentID = b.AccountID
                WHERE (a.FirstTransactionDT between '6/1/2014' and '5/31/2015'
                AND a.CashAmount > '0'
                AND a.GivingYear = '2015'
                AND A.GivingYear !< '2015')
                AND (b.GiftReceivedDt between '6/1/2014' and '5/31/2015'
                AND b.RecordTypeID != '0'
                AND b.RecordTypeID != '-1'
                AND b.RecordTypeID != '2'))



                FROM FundConstituentTotals'
```

Suggested Response Results:

```
ConstituentID   FundConstituentTotalID  ConstituentID   GivingYear  PledgeAmount    CashAmount  NonCashAmount   FirstTrans
        49427                    77314          49427        2015              0           25          0             1/13/2015
        49427   77314   49427   2015    0   25  0   1/13/2015
        49427   77314   49427   2015    0   25  0   1/13/2015
        49427   77314   49427   2015    0   25  0   1/13/2015
```

Just found that the data is innacurate, FirstTransactionDate does not provide the date of the first transaction, just the date the transaction begin being posted to the ledger (SOMEONE MESSED THIS UP IN THE PAST). I will have to use GiftReceivedDate between DATES, and find a way to remove people if they have dates prior to 2014.

Comment: Dates adhere to a specific format in SQL. This isn't it.

Comment: I apologize my date format isn't accurate, it still pulls the correct date range though.

Comment: iwcSQL does Rubix's solution solve your problem? If not, please comment and provide more info, and if it does, it would be good for you to accept as an answer if it covers what you need it to :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT  Number_Of_New_Donors = ( SELECT  COUNT(a.ConstituentID) 
                From dbo.FundConstituentTotals a
                LEFT JOIN dbo.FundLedger b
                ON a.ConstituentID = b.AccountID
                    AND a.LastTransactionDate = b.GiftReceivedDt
                WHERE a.FirstTransactionDT between '2015-01-01' and '2015-05-31'
                AND b.AppealCode != 2)
```

This seems to do what you want. FirstTransaction is this year (since it is the first, there can't be previous ones), and appeal code isn't 2. What is the rest of your code trying to do?

Comment: Could conceivably change the `WHERE` clause to use `YEAR(a.FirstTransactionDT)` rather than `BETWEEN`? 

(Unless FY is financial year and thus a range... **if so** what is the range of the 2015 financial year and is this what you are looking for?)

Comment: Nice addition. OP wasn't clear whether it was "this year" or if "between 6/1/2014 and today" was the important one... So I merged the two lol

Comment: I am not sure why this isn't working, but it gives me information similar to the following, with duplicates, and such. Will post results in top.

Comment: Looks like multiple entries in the ledger could be the cause of this, especially if a constituent is giving multiples times this year. This could be indicating recurring payments, perhaps.

Anyways, I've edited the code in order to eliminate this by only joining the constituent with their last gift (instead of all gifts given). Also changed to a left join since we are most interested in unique entries in the Constituent table (although this won't effect the output any which way)

Comment: This is almost perfect. Any idea how to remove people if given previously? The data in FirstTransactionDT is not accurate. So I will have to find anyone who has given this year in another column in fundledger "GiftReceivedDT", and remove anyone who has given before 2015.

Comment: Hmm, you'd have to trim the data in fundledger to only include those names who have never given before 2015. Some thing like 

SELECT AccountID
FROM fundledger
WHERE min( YEAR(GiftReceivedDt) ) == 2015
GROUP BY AccountID

and use it to trim down the fundledger list

SELECT * FROM fundledger WHERE accountID in (previous query)